# Richfaces 4: How to change ribbon options of a <rich:editor>

Tags: jsf-2, ckeditor, richfaces, rich-text-editor

I am using `<rich:editor>` in my application and I need customize the ribbon options of the editor(I want to have only some option and omit the others). Is anybody know where will I get all possible values for  configuration ?

And the following is what I tried till now

```
<f:facet name="config">
                toolbar: 'custom',
                language: '#{editorBean.language}',
                startupFocus: true,
                toolbar_custom:
                    [
                        { name: 'basicstyles', items : ['Bold','Italic'] },
                        { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Paste','PasteFromWord'] },
                        { name: 'basicstyles', items : ['Underline'] },
                        { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent'] },
                        { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent'] },
                    ]
</f:facet>
```

Comment: This link has all necessary configurations http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Toolbar

Answer (score 0):

From richfaces documentation : http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=editor&sample=advancedConfiguration&skin=blueSky

You can see available configuration from CKEditor API here : http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/index.html
http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html